# Is it possible to make an editable textarea readonly using javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML textarea. I want it so that the user can input anything, but if a certain function is called, the box is made readonly. Is it possible to create such function? And, if yes, then how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

```
 document.getElementById("myTextarea").readOnly = "true";
```

Comment: `readOnly` is a [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) propery, so it probably should be  `true`, not `"true"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function readOnlyTextArea(idTextArea){
    document.getElementById(idTextArea).readOnly = "true";
};
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c7vms3h7/)

Answer (score -1):

**jsfiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/kenhkw3s/

**HTML :**

```
<textarea id="details"></textarea>
```

**Script :**

```
document.getElementById("details").readOnly = "true";
```

Comment: Downvoted for Misinformation. Try putting document.getElementById("details").readOnly = "false"; in your JS fiddle, and typing into your textarea - It will still remain readonly because any non-empty string is still TRUTHY; what you need is a boolean, not a string.